Adjetivo para experto en tecnología
En más de una ocasión utilice techie para definir el perfil de trabajador buscado: un experimentado en tecnología.

Un becario techie


En mi caso particular, no se trata de alguien conocedor máximo de cada tecnología, sino que esté habituado al uso, de modo que al explicarle algo simple sepa cómo desenvolverse.

Pensaba que era una palabra que me había inventado, pero leyendo esta respuesta de English SE veo que existe.
¿Hay alternativa en castellano?
Técnico es demasiado genérico e Informático muy específico.
Geek es la que más se acerca, pero estoy como al comienzo, otro anglicismo.

Yo conocía el término pero con distinta grafía: tekkie (que también aparece así en varios diccionarios ingleses). Nótese además que no implica necesariamente experiencia ya que puede ser solo entusiasmo. No conozco alternativa en castellano.

ChatGPT me propone "tecnófilo", pero no me gusta

"Tecnólogo" sería lo más adecuado aunque no es una palabra muy utilizada en el lenguaje coloquial. Existe la palabra "manitas" aunque resulta muy genérica más propia del ámbito del bricolaje y no de la tecnología.

In English techie is an informal word. I would not use it in an official job description although it might be used in informal conversations about the role we were trying to fill.

Coincido en qué "tecnólogo" sería la palabra que definiría de forma general a un experto en tecnología, pero parece demasiado genérica y vaga como "futurólogo"; no suena tan específica como "meteorólogo". Creo que en castellano usual, lo adecuado sería "técnico informático", "técnico electrónico", "técnico de sistemas", "técnico X", etc,... aplicado a la especialidad aludida, y siempre que no haya un término ya predeterminado como por ejemplo: "programador", que vendría a ser "técnico en desarrollo de software". Cambiar "técnico" por "especialista en x" tampoco me parece mala opción.

In English,techie is definitely a slang term and may not always be applied to professionals but generally someone who is a whizz with technology. As I hate,when anglocisms are consistently and lazily borrowed,especiallywith technology/beauty and fashion,i am glad o see words like''tecnólogo and tecnófilo used. I appreciate ,though they don't seem to be so popular by all.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Dependiendo del tipo de experto que se busque, la expresión "profesional TIC" o "experto TIC" podría servir, siendo TIC el acrónimo de "Tecnologías de la Información y la Comunicación", y entiendo que se ajustaría bastante al concepto de techie que normalmente hace referencia a gente con conocimientos en TIC más que, por ejemplo, a especialistas en astrofísica o mecánica de fluidos.

Cada campo tiene un cierto grado de influencia y tolerancia a los extranjerismos. No veo razón práctica para descartar anglicismos en un anuncio de una vacante, de hecho podría resultar contraproducente si el público que deseas atraer no está familizado con otros términos.
Experimentado en tecnología es muy genérico ya que existen muchísmos campos de práctica tecnológica. Llevando esto al extremo cualquier técnica es sujeta a agruparse con técnicas similares y quien tenga experiencia en ese conjunto de técnicas podría ser considerado experto.
Debido a la actual ominipresencia de computadoras u ordernadores, es usual asumir que un experto en tecnología sería experto en las técnicas y dispositivos asociadas a estos aparatos, sin embargo, un experto en tecnología de alimentos podría tener muy poca expericia en el uso de computadoras comparado con un integrador de sistemas computacionales.
Cómo no has indicado detalles, ¿qué tal si consultas a un grupo de becarios y les preguntas cómo les quedaría más claro de que se trata la vacante?

Y vas a sudar TINTA para encontrar una palabra en español que sea tan descriptiva como “techie”.
Puedes usar quizás una frase, pero un adjetivo que describa tal cual el concepto.. lo dudo.
Un as, gurú, lumbrera, geniecillo son las opciones más viables… a mi criterio.

No se si haya un equvalente de una sóla palabra.
Formalmente, a quien posea un ese perfil, apto técnicamente con la suficiente solvencia en el campo tecnológico, se lo puede calificar como "técnico idóneo en programación", "informático calificado", o "técnico-informático competente"
Una forma intermedia sería requerir

un becario  ducho en tecnología


PD: Aprovecho para mencionar un término muy informal que conozco en los grupos con los que trabajo (programadores, QAs y gente de IT en Argentina) que aunque no se ajuste al nivel de formalidad requerido para la solicitud de un becario, viene a colación como equivalente a las voces sajonas de "techie" y "nerd" . En esos contextos, toda vez que alguno de nosotros esté hablando de algún aspecto técnico demasiado erudito o especializado, recibirá el apelativo de:

ñoño

No tengo idea de cuán extendida sea esa calificación, basada en el perfil de un personaje mexicano (Ñoño) de una de las series de humor mas conocidas en Latino-América llamada "El Chavo del Ocho". Ñoño es un personaje secundario de esa serie —altamente popular en que dejó de producirse hace como 25 años pero siguió por décadas en todas las programaciones—  y compone un niño obeso, socialmente retraido y estudioso, que típicamente, responde primero y exhaustivamente todas las preguntas que hace el maestro en clase.
El término, en el uso que menciono, puede mutarse a verbo, o sustantivo; si alguno refiere asuntos técnicamente profundos, y  fuera de un contexto especializado, se dirá que "ya comenzó a 'ñoñear', o tirar 'ñoñeadas' (por lo dicho el uso se acercaría más al sentido de "nerd", que implica un poco a "techie" pero tiene la característica de no ser un anglicismo, y portar un cariz más jocoso, hasta más cariñoso, que el más derogativo "nerd" —probablmente por tratarse El Chavo de un producto de humor, con la clave de una ternura tan ingenua como divertida)
